# Generate few us short delay in GNU Linux

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded-linux

I am trying to generate a short delay between two calls writing HW based registers in GNU C on ARM (Linux).

It looks like the system latency is too high when I am using usleep() or nanosleep() functions.

The following code fragment

```
struct timespec ts;
  ts.tv_sec   = 0;
  ts.tv_nsec  = 1;   // 1 nano second
  //...
  do{ } while (nanosleep(&ts, &ts));
```

results in over 100 us delay (comparing when present or commented out).

What is the way around? Since my desired delay is approximately 2 us I can possibly live even with a blocking function.

As @Lubo hinted I cannot rely on reliable delay generated within my code since that may be interrupted.

The HW register I am writing needs ~ 1us between two consequent writes.

If I want to generate a *shortest possible delay at least 2us* and won't mind getting longer delay in cases I get interrupted I may still be fine. In total I may acquire less delay compared to the current state when every time I am getting 100us more than intended.

Comment: I don't think that you can do this in linux mainly due to the scheduler. Your code can be interrupted (and will be) even during the delay which will result in higher delay as you want. Maybe ask a different question: what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Does your HW and kernel have high-resolution timers, aka hrtimers?  E.G. check the **/proc/timer_list** file.